# Extract number from filename

Tags: bash

I'm doing a bash script, which automatically can run simulations for me. In order to start the simulation, this other script need an input, which should be dictated by the name of the folder.

So if I have a folder names No200, then I want to extract the number 200. So far, what I have is

```
PedsDirs=`find . -type d -maxdepth 1`
for dir in $PedsDirs
do
        if [ $dir != "." ]; then
            NoOfPeds = "Number appearing in the name dir" 
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ dir="No200"
$ echo "${dir#No}"
200
```

In general, to remove a prefix use `${variable-name#prefix}`; to remove a suffix: `${variable-name%suffix}`.

---

**Bonus tip:** avoid using `find`. It introduces many problems, especially when your files/directories contain whitespace. Use bash builtins glob features instead:

```
for dir in No*/           # Loops over all directories starting with 'No'.
do
    dir="${dir%/}"        # Removes the trailing slash from the directory name.
    NoOfPeds="${dir#No}"  # Removes the 'No' prefix.
done
```

Also, try to always use quotes around variable names to avoid accidental expansion (i.e. use `"$dir"` instead of just `$dir`).

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, as you have to join the `=` to the variable name in bash. To get *just* the number, you can do something like:

```
NoOfPeds=`echo $dir | tr -d -c 0-9`
```

(that is, delete whatever char that it is not a number). All numbers will be then in `NoOfPeds`.